# How to download files from FTPS in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, winscp-net

Our IT department gave me credentials for an FTPS, which I can access using FileZilla

But I also need to access the FTPS using an application I am working on to automate the process. The information provided to me was,

That this is an FTP over TLS/SSL

**IP**: xxx.xxx.xx.xx

**Port**: 990 <-- suggesting its an implicit encryption

**UserName**: username.ftp

**Password:** password123

After reading some posts on WinSCP on stack and their documentation, I still can't access the ftps using my application. My code so far..

```
        SessionOptions sessionOp = new SessionOptions()
        {
            FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Implicit,
            Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
            HostName = IP,              
            UserName = userName,
            Password = password,
        };

        sessionOp.AddRawSettings("ProxyMethod", "3");
        sessionOp.AddRawSettings("ProxyPort", "990");

        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            session.Open(sessionOp);
            var list = session.ListDirectory(dir);
            Console.WriteLine(list);
        }
```

The error I get is, "Failed to Connect" from WinSCP

How can I access this FTPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is configuring the HTTP Proxy port to 990. Instead you should configure the FTPS port.

```
SessionOptions sessionOp = new SessionOptions()
{
    FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Implicit,
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = IP,              
    UserName = userName,
    Password = password,
    PortNumber = 990
};
```

and remove the lines

```
sessionOp.AddRawSettings("ProxyMethod", "3");
sessionOp.AddRawSettings("ProxyPort", "990");
```

Also, I suggest using [the WinSCP GUI](https://winscp.net) to try this instead of FileZilla, considering that the library is related to the GUI.

Comment: okay, now I am getting new error, which means progress? It says, peer certificate rejected

Comment: @Adas: look for TlsClientCertificatePath or TlsHostCertificateFingerprint or GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnyTlsHostCertificate

Comment: No need to set `PortNumber = 990` – That's the default for `FtpSecure.Implicit` + For *"peer certificate rejected"* use `TlsHostCertificateFingerprint` (`GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnyTlsHostCertificate` is not secure and `TlsClientCertificatePath` is for client not server certificate) + In general, it's easier to setup the connection in WinSCP GUI and have it [generate a code template for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code). To get the value for `TlsHostCertificateFingerprint`, you need to login before generating the code. +1

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That is a nice feature, it's now working with the tls certificate approach